# Possible: Sailsjs with both NoSQL and SQL?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have an idea to use both NoSQL (Google datastore) and SQL (google SQL) together in my nodejs project hosted on Google cloud platform. The reason for this is because I want to keep the statistics, massive amount of data, away from the mySQL db. It will create to many writes, a lot cheaper and faster to use noSQL for this purpose.

I cannot use noSQL for the entire site, the project has already been created with mySQL.

Is this possible? If so please share any guidelines to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using sails.js (waterline) you can define as many connections as you want. And then in the model you can select the connection that you want to use.

It is very cool, 2 models, using 2 different connections (mysql - gdatastore) can even have relations between one and the other one.

basically in your model you have to set the connection key `{ connection: 'mysqldb'}`

here you can find the documentation: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/configuration.md

Answer (score 1):

```
#model   
 module.exports.connections = {
      localMysql: {
        adapter: 'sails-mysql',
        user: 'root',
        host: 'localhost',
        database: 'someDbase'
      },
      remoteMysql: {
        adapter: 'sails-mysql',
        user: 'remoteUser',
        password: 'remotePassword',
        host: 'http://remote-mysql-host.com',
        database: 'remoteDbase'
      },
      localMongo:{
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    ......
    }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but cannot use that with Google datastore?

Comment: you can, is a little bit dificult because you should create your cumstom adapter: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-adapter-boilerplate